# Does iq unique constraint make writing to database table slower

Tags: c#, wpf, database, visual-studio, sybase

In my table schema, the iq unique constraint is set to 255. When I try to update the database table using the odbcdataadapter in c#, the update instruction takes a long time to execute. I was wondering if it is due to the iq unique constraint set to be true. I came to this conclusion when I try to write to another database with iq unique option set to off and the update happens quicker. I am using sybase.

```
column_name    data_type    nullable    iq unique
A <pk>         timestamp    not null    255
B <pk>         integer      not null    255
C<pk>          integer      not null    255
D <pk>         varchar(10)  not null    255
E              double       not null    255
F              varchar(2500)not null    255
G              varchar(64)  not null    255
H<pk>          timestamp    not null    255

OdbcConnection my_conn;
OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(my_conn.CreateCommand());
DataTable my_dt = new DataTable();
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select * from my_table where 1=2";
adapter.Fill(my_dt);
process(my_dt);
adapter.Update(my_dt); //takes a really long time
```

Comment: Please show us your odbcdataadapter code, the sql string you are trying to execute, and your table schema.  If possible.

Comment: Read: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1510/html/iqapgv1/CEGIEJBI.htm,

Comment: From my understanding of the documentation, setting iq unique constraint would cause a bit more to be going on, checking to make sure the item is unique which would need the entry to be cross referenced against all other entries to see if it's truly unique. This action would cause a longer working time due to these checks.

Comment: have added the code for reference.

Comment: No index?  How many records do you have the in table?  5 comparisons per record (varchar and timestamp too) without an index would _probably_ be the cause of the slowdown.